# Анализ программы с помощью valgrind

Tags: c

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько у меня все плохо с программой? Просто смущает 1,122 allocs и 357 free, хотя везде все освобождал

Comment: а почему Ваш выбор упал на valgrind если есть libasan????

Answer (score 0):

> Насколько у меня все плохо с программой? Просто смущает 1,122 allocs и 357 free, хотя везде все освобождал

Должны смущать сильно ненулевые значения в `definitly lost` и `inderectly lost`. Если ни каких сторонних библиотек не используешь, то с программой всё не хорошо... Для того, чтобы valgrind показывал простыню с конкретными местами утечки, добавь ему ключи `--leak-check=full` и `--track-origins=yes`.

---

Дальнейшее чтение: [*How do I use valgrind to find memory leaks?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134891/how-do-i-use-valgrind-to-find-memory-leaks) на enSO.

---

И ради бога, вставляй текстовую информацию текстом, а не скриншотами...

Comment: А под винду можно valgrind использовать?